# Does Flask automatically delete aborted large file upload?

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

My Flask application will allow the upload of large files (up to 100 Mb) to my server. I was wondering how Flask managed the chunked file if the client decides to stop the upload half way.  I read the [documentation about File Upload](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/) but wasn't able to find that mentioned.

Does Flask automatically delete the file?  How can it know that the user won't retry it?  Or do I have to manually delete the aborted files in the temporary folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Werkzeug (the library that Flask uses for many tasks including this one) uses a [`tempfile.TemporaryFile` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) to receive the WSGI file stream when uploading. The object automatically manages the open file.

- The file is immediately deleted on disk; there is no entry in the directory table anymore, but the process retains a file handle
- When the `TemporaryFile` object is cleared (no references remain, usually because the request ended), the file object is closed and the operating system clears the disk space used.

As such, the file data is deleted when a request is aborted.

Flask does not handle the case where a user uploads the file again; there is no standard way to handle that anyway. You'd have to come up with your own solution there.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! This raise a small question ; is it possible to send a large file chuncked using Flask (with no modules) ? Or, as you said "Flask does not handle the case where a user uploads the file again", this means it does not support chuncked upload out of the box ?

Comment: @CyrilN.: chunked uploading is still one connection; I'm talking about a *user* aborting the upload and later resuming the upload, not the protocol sending data in chunks.

Comment: @CyrilN.: Note that `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` support depends on the WSGI server, by the way, not Flask. It is the HTTP layer that needs to handle this, but Flask (properly deployed) doesn't handle that layer as it is a WSGI application, not a WSGI server (the built-in development server doesn't count and should not be used in production).

Comment: Duly noted! Thank you for the precisions :)